# Ruby on rails - Pass text_field's value in form to a parameter for an action in a different controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a form which has this text field

```
<%= f.text_field :content %>
```

I have a link_to tag to post the value of the text field to an action present in another controller. I need to be able to get the value of the text field and say

```
<%= link_to 'post', :controller => "a_different_controller", :action => "update", :message => "text field's value" %>
```

Can you please help me out here?

I tried various options posted on stack overflow. None seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to POST a value without a html form, you must do this via javascript. You can create a onClick listener for that link, and in the listener grab the value of that text_field and submit the form via javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mike. Yes, I did add it to the link_to tag. onclick => "get_content()". And wrote this function. function get_content()
 {
  return getElementById('tweet_content').value;
 } My question now is how do I set the "getElementById('tweet_content').value" to the :message parameter that I need to send to the 'update' action within another controller.

Comment: getElementById('message').value = getElementById('tweet_content').value

form.submit() //where form is the form element.

Comment: Oh. message is not a form element. Its just the parameter name I use to pass the text field's value to the update action in another controller as soon as the link is clicked. Did I understand your solution right?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the `remote` and `method` options on your `link_to` helper:

```
<%= link_to 'Post', yourmodel_path, :remote => true, :method => :put %>
```

That will submit it via ajax. If you don't want that and you just want to use the PUT HTTP verb, you can drop the `:remote => true` portion.

Note that I'm using the shorthand way of referring to the action you are targeting. If you're not familiar with that, I suggest you run through the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/)…it's pretty core to understanding example code.