# Pass text_field value with link_to

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

```
<%= text_field_tag 'search_name', :class => 'search_save' %>
<%= link_to "Save search" , save_search_path(@some_value), :remote => true, :method => :post %>
```

Is there any way to pass search_name text field's value with the given link??

Comment: @some_value is a Hash.So I think I can't use $.post(url,{params} like method.I have to use link_to.

Comment: I think you can use "submit" instead of "link_to" for 'Save search'. This would submit your form parameters. You could then add another submit for your main commit, routed to the appropriate action.

Comment: @cdesrosiers But I don't want to use form..

Comment: @some_value is a hash? What does "save_search_path" looks like? Something like "/search/save/:id"? You can check it by running "rake routes" at the command prompt.

Comment: @shajin I assumed you had text_field_tag inside of a form.

Comment: @YosepKim its - post '/save_search' => 'cont#action', :as => save_search -  and the hash will pass like query parameters..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're trying to post a value to the server you should be using an HTML form. That's what they're designed for. In fact, when you specify `:method => :post` as on option for the `link_to` helper, Rails dynamically creates an HTML form that is immediately sent when the link is clicked. Why not just do this?

```
<%= form_tag '/save_search' do -%>
  <%= text_field_tag 'search_name', :class => 'search_save' %>

  <%= submit_tag 'Save search' %>
<% end -%>
```

This will post the value to the server (accessible as `params[:search_name]` inside the controller action) like required.

If its an issue of aesthetics (as in, you think buttons are ugly and want links instead) you can always style the submit button to look like a link with plain old CSS. To the user it will look like a link but more importantly it will behave like a button and submit the form without any additional logic.

If you're still not convinced that using a form is the way to go and you're keen on making it work, you can do so with jQuery. Let's take your example code and modify it slightly

```
<%= text_field_tag 'search_name', :class => 'search_save' %>
<%= link_to "Save search" , save_search_path(@some_value), :id => 'save_search' %>
```

Then inside your `application.js` you can add the following.

```
$(function() {
    // Add click event binding to `Save search` link
    $("#save_search").on("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // don't trigger default

        // get the value inside the text field
        var name = $("#search_name").val();

        $.post('/save_search', { search_name: name }, function(data) {
            // log the result from the server, or whatever...
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
});
```

This event will get fired when someone clicks on the "Save search" link and will make an AJAX call to the server with the specified data (unless the user did something silly like disable JavaScript). The controller action will be able to access this data via `params[:search_name]`. Hope this helps. Happy coding!

Comment: This answer uses `form_tag` and `submit_tag` the question asks how to use `text_field_tag` and `link_to`.  It's import because some times there is already a form and forms can't be nested.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a duplicate with [Ruby on rails - Pass text_field's value in form to a parameter for an action in a different controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285513/ruby-on-rails-pass-text-fields-value-in-form-to-a-parameter-for-an-action-in)

But here is an answer: http://railspikes.com/2007/4/17/partial_dom_submit_with_link_to_remote

It might need to be modified for newer versions of rails. The `:submit` option doesn't seem to be there any more.  If the link goes to a `GET` action, you can use a javascript change event to change the `href` on the link.  I'm sure there is a way to do this with `POST` actions too.

And I used this page to get it working: https://makandracards.com/makandra/1383-rails-3-make-link_to-remote-true-replace-html-elements-with-jquery